# SQL SUM values of month, compare with same days of same month from previous year for specific names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, join

So consider the following tables:

```html
CREATE TABLE meters (meterentryid int, datasourcetag varchar(20));
 
INSERT INTO meters (meterentryid, datasourcetag) VALUES
('1', 'HABCQW'),
('2', 'BBBWEQ'),
('3', 'CCCQWD'),
('4', 'DDDQWD'),
('5', 'QABCDQ'),
('6', 'GABCQDT');

create table meter_values (meterentryid int, summary_value int, startdate datetime);

insert into meter_values (meterentryid, startdate, summary_value) values
('1','2013-09-01','8400'),
('2','2013-09-01','7500'),
('3','2013-09-01','8100'),
('4','2013-09-01','7500'),
('5','2013-09-01','9300'),
('6','2013-09-01','7100'),
('1','2013-10-01','84'),
('2','2013-10-01','75'),
('3','2013-10-01','81'),
('4','2013-10-01','75'),
('5','2013-10-01','93'),
('6','2013-10-01','71'),
('1','2013-10-02','76'),
('2','2013-10-02','94'),
('3','2013-10-02','91'),
('4','2013-10-02','92'),
('5','2013-10-02','93'),
('6','2013-10-02','72'),
('1','2013-10-03','92'),
('2','2013-10-03','70'),
('3','2013-10-03','75'),
('4','2013-10-03','84'),
('5','2013-10-03','76'),
('6','2013-10-03','77'),
('1','2013-10-04','91'),
('2','2013-10-04','97'),
('3','2013-10-04','93'),
('4','2013-10-04','85'),
('5','2013-10-04','79'),
('6','2013-10-04','98'),
('1','2013-10-05','98'),
('2','2013-10-05','85'),
('3','2013-10-05','95'),
('4','2013-10-05','98'),
('5','2013-10-05','86'),
('6','2013-10-05','95'),
('1','2013-10-06','97'),
('2','2013-10-06','75'),
('3','2013-10-06','98'),
('4','2013-10-06','94'),
('5','2013-10-06','97'),
('6','2013-10-06','84'),
('1','2013-10-07','81'),
('2','2013-10-07','96'),
('3','2013-10-07','94'),
('4','2013-10-07','98'),
('5','2013-10-07','96'),
('6','2013-10-07','79'),
('1','2013-10-08','86'),
('2','2013-10-08','100'),
('3','2013-10-08','79'),
('4','2013-10-08','98'),
('5','2013-10-08','95'),
('6','2013-10-08','85'),
('1','2013-10-09','72'),
('2','2013-10-09','94'),
('3','2013-10-09','76'),
('4','2013-10-09','86'),
('5','2013-10-09','76'),
('6','2013-10-09','98'),
('1','2013-10-10','93'),
('2','2013-10-10','94'),
('3','2013-10-10','75'),
('4','2013-10-10','80'),
('5','2013-10-10','99'),
('6','2013-10-10','77'),
('1','2013-10-11','72'),
('2','2013-10-11','84'),
('3','2013-10-11','93'),
('4','2013-10-11','74'),
('5','2013-10-11','89'),
('6','2013-10-11','70'),
('1','2013-10-12','100'),
('2','2013-10-12','71'),
('3','2013-10-12','81'),
('4','2013-10-12','98'),
('5','2013-10-12','85'),
('6','2013-10-12','92'),
('1','2013-10-13','77'),
('2','2013-10-13','75'),
('3','2013-10-13','95'),
('4','2013-10-13','74'),
('5','2013-10-13','95'),
('6','2013-10-13','91'),
('1','2013-10-14','97'),
('2','2013-10-14','91'),
('3','2013-10-14','79'),
('4','2013-10-14','73'),
('5','2013-10-14','89'),
('6','2013-10-14','85'),
('1','2013-10-15','83'),
('2','2013-10-15','74'),
('3','2013-10-15','91'),
('4','2013-10-15','100'),
('5','2013-10-15','89'),
('6','2013-10-15','88'),
('1','2013-10-16','77'),
('2','2013-10-16','70'),
('3','2013-10-16','76'),
('4','2013-10-16','72'),
('5','2013-10-16','77'),
('6','2013-10-16','89'),
('1','2013-10-17','80'),
('2','2013-10-17','81'),
('3','2013-10-17','79'),
('4','2013-10-17','73'),
('5','2013-10-17','83'),
('6','2013-10-17','93'),
('1','2013-10-18','80'),
('2','2013-10-18','72'),
('3','2013-10-18','94'),
('4','2013-10-18','73'),
('5','2013-10-18','76'),
('6','2013-10-18','96'),
('1','2013-10-19','97'),
('2','2013-10-19','98'),
('3','2013-10-19','96'),
('4','2013-10-19','83'),
('5','2013-10-19','87'),
('6','2013-10-19','97'),
('1','2013-10-20','75'),
('2','2013-10-20','86'),
('3','2013-10-20','78'),
('4','2013-10-20','73'),
('5','2013-10-20','84'),
('6','2013-10-20','100'),
('1','2013-10-21','70'),
('2','2013-10-21','87'),
('3','2013-10-21','98'),
('4','2013-10-21','99'),
('5','2013-10-21','74'),
('6','2013-10-21','77'),
('1','2013-10-22','77'),
('2','2013-10-22','90'),
('3','2013-10-22','83'),
('4','2013-10-22','93'),
('5','2013-10-22','77'),
('6','2013-10-22','90'),
('1','2013-10-23','83'),
('2','2013-10-23','92'),
('3','2013-10-23','78'),
('4','2013-10-23','86'),
('5','2013-10-23','84'),
('6','2013-10-23','77'),
('1','2013-10-24','82'),
('2','2013-10-24','83'),
('3','2013-10-24','81'),
('4','2013-10-24','83'),
('5','2013-10-24','72'),
('6','2013-10-24','72'),
('1','2013-10-25','75'),
('2','2013-10-25','79'),
('3','2013-10-25','87'),
('4','2013-10-25','86'),
('5','2013-10-25','89'),
('6','2013-10-25','96'),
('1','2013-10-26','88'),
('2','2013-10-26','89'),
('3','2013-10-26','100'),
('4','2013-10-26','81'),
('5','2013-10-26','88'),
('6','2013-10-26','78'),
('1','2013-10-27','100'),
('2','2013-10-27','98'),
('3','2013-10-27','70'),
('4','2013-10-27','81'),
('5','2013-10-27','94'),
('6','2013-10-27','73'),
('1','2013-10-28','86'),
('2','2013-10-28','83'),
('3','2013-10-28','85'),
('4','2013-10-28','100'),
('5','2013-10-28','70'),
('6','2013-10-28','98'),
('1','2013-10-29','82'),
('2','2013-10-29','78'),
('3','2013-10-29','74'),
('4','2013-10-29','86'),
('5','2013-10-29','87'),
('6','2013-10-29','71'),
('1','2013-10-30','88'),
('2','2013-10-30','71'),
('3','2013-10-30','97'),
('4','2013-10-30','95'),
('5','2013-10-30','97'),
('6','2013-10-30','81'),
('1','2013-10-31','96'),
('2','2013-10-31','78'),
('3','2013-10-31','82'),
('4','2013-10-31','74'),
('5','2013-10-31','84'),
('6','2013-10-31','95'),
('1','2014-10-01','70'),
('2','2014-10-01','97'),
('3','2014-10-01','73'),
('4','2014-10-01','79'),
('5','2014-10-01','81'),
('6','2014-10-01','81'),
('1','2014-10-02','70'),
('2','2014-10-02','73'),
('3','2014-10-02','85'),
('4','2014-10-02','78'),
('5','2014-10-02','81'),
('6','2014-10-02','74'),
('1','2014-10-03','74'),
('2','2014-10-03','93'),
('3','2014-10-03','81'),
('4','2014-10-03','70'),
('5','2014-10-03','83'),
('6','2014-10-03','79'),
('1','2014-10-04','80'),
('2','2014-10-04','97'),
('3','2014-10-04','96'),
('4','2014-10-04','89'),
('5','2014-10-04','79'),
('6','2014-10-04','98'),
('1','2014-10-05','83'),
('2','2014-10-05','95'),
('3','2014-10-05','96'),
('4','2014-10-05','77'),
('5','2014-10-05','77'),
('6','2014-10-05','71'),
('1','2014-10-06','96'),
('2','2014-10-06','89'),
('3','2014-10-06','99'),
('4','2014-10-06','83'),
('5','2014-10-06','90'),
('6','2014-10-06','89'),
('1','2014-10-07','98'),
('2','2014-10-07','76'),
('3','2014-10-07','86'),
('4','2014-10-07','79'),
('5','2014-10-07','76'),
('6','2014-10-07','97'),
('1','2014-10-08','94'),
('2','2014-10-08','78'),
('3','2014-10-08','83'),
('4','2014-10-08','90'),
('5','2014-10-08','92'),
('6','2014-10-08','91'),
('1','2014-10-09','90'),
('2','2014-10-09','85'),
('3','2014-10-09','84'),
('4','2014-10-09','90'),
('5','2014-10-09','95'),
('6','2014-10-09','94'),
('1','2014-10-10','94'),
('2','2014-10-10','81'),
('3','2014-10-10','78'),
('4','2014-10-10','74'),
('5','2014-10-10','90'),
('6','2014-10-10','74'),
('1','2014-10-11','98'),
('2','2014-10-11','83'),
('3','2014-10-11','79'),
('4','2014-10-11','87'),
('5','2014-10-11','93'),
('6','2014-10-11','78'),
('1','2014-10-12','96'),
('2','2014-10-12','77'),
('3','2014-10-12','74'),
('4','2014-10-12','99'),
('5','2014-10-12','84'),
('6','2014-10-12','95'),
('1','2014-10-13','74'),
('2','2014-10-13','97'),
('3','2014-10-13','99'),
('4','2014-10-13','82'),
('5','2014-10-13','72'),
('6','2014-10-13','73'),
('1','2014-10-14','96'),
('2','2014-10-14','78'),
('3','2014-10-14','91'),
('4','2014-10-14','97'),
('5','2014-10-14','76'),
('6','2014-10-14','84'),
('1','2014-10-15','98'),
('2','2014-10-15','81'),
('3','2014-10-15','100'),
('4','2014-10-15','93'),
('5','2014-10-15','90'),
('6','2014-10-15','78'),
('1','2014-10-16','81'),
('2','2014-10-16','94'),
('3','2014-10-16','97');
```

Table [meters] has ID and Name, table [meter_values] has the value logged for each of the meters on a given date.

I want to specify a date (externally), for example '2014-10-10', check until which day of the selected month I have values on [meter_values]. Fetch the corresponding values from last year (same month, up until the same day) and compare them on the same line. So if on the selected date's year I only have values until day 16, I should only compare with values up until day 16 from the last Years month, despite having all the values.
This should be done only for meters that have the name 'ABC' on them.

So the result table should look something like this (haven't done the math manually to check):

```html
Selected_Year | Previous_Year | Name
1392       | 1376       | HABCQW
1259       | 1414       | QABCDQ
1256       | 1351       | GABCQDT
```

I have managed to hammer my way down onto the following SQL code which I'm a bit ashamed to show you guys

```html
select final.Selected_Year, final.Previous_Year, datasourcetag from
(
Select table1.sum_summary_value as 'Selected_Year', table2.sum_summary_value as 'Previous_Year', table1.MeterEntryID from
(
SELECT sum([Summary_Value]) as 'sum_summary_value', meters.MeterEntryID, DATEPART(yyyy,startdate) as 'Years'
FROM meter_values
INNER JOIN meters
ON meters.MeterEntryID=meter_values.MeterEntryID
where DataSourceTag like '%ABC%' and
DATEPART(dd,startdate) <= DATEPART(dd,
(
select top 1 startdate 
from meter_values
where 
datepart(mm,[StartDate])=datepart(mm,'2014-10-20') 
and datepart(yyyy,[StartDate])=datepart(yyyy,'2014-10-20') 
order by startdate desc
)
)
and 
(datepart(yyyy,[StartDate])=datepart(yyyy,'2014-10-20') 
or
datepart(yyyy,[StartDate])=datepart(yyyy,dateadd(yyyy,-1,'2014-10-20'))) 
and datepart(mm,[StartDate])=datepart(mm,'2014-10-20') 
group by METERS.MeterEntryID , DATEPART(yyyy,startdate) , DATEPART(mm,startdate)
) 
table1
full join
(
SELECT sum([Summary_Value]) as 'sum_summary_value', meters.MeterEntryID, DATEPART(yyyy,startdate) as 'Years'
FROM meter_values
INNER JOIN meters
ON meters.MeterEntryID=meter_values.MeterEntryID
where DataSourceTag like '%ABC%' and
DATEPART(dd,startdate) <= DATEPART(dd,
(
select top 1 startdate 
from meter_values
where 
datepart(mm,[StartDate])=datepart(mm,'2014-10-20') 
and datepart(yyyy,[StartDate])=datepart(yyyy,'2014-10-20') 
order by startdate desc
)
)
and 
(datepart(yyyy,[StartDate])=datepart(yyyy,'2014-10-20') 
or
datepart(yyyy,[StartDate])=datepart(yyyy,dateadd(yyyy,-1,'2014-10-20'))) 
and datepart(mm,[StartDate])=datepart(mm,'2014-10-20') 
group by METERS.MeterEntryID , DATEPART(yyyy,startdate) , DATEPART(mm,startdate)
)  
table2  
on table1.MeterEntryID=table2.MeterEntryID
where table1.years=datepart(yyyy,'2014-10-20') and table2.years=datepart(yyyy,dateadd(yyyy,-1,'2014-10-20')) 
)
final
inner join dbo.meters
on dbo.meters.meterentryid=final.meterentryid
```

This seems to work, but besides beeing ridiculously ugly, I need one other thing that I have no idea how to achieve. From all the meters that have 'ABC' on the name, if one of them has values up until day 25 for example, my code considers that ALL of the meters have values up until day 25.
How can I manage to get correct results (if each meter has values up until different days)?

I'm using MS SQL 2008.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with conditional aggregation.  Here is an approach

```
select m.name,
       sum(case when year(startdate) = 2014 and day(startdate) <= 10 then summary_value end) as thisyear,
       sum(case when year(startdate) = 2013 and day(startdate) <= 10 then summary_value end) as lastyear
from meters m join
     meter_values mv
     on m.meterentryid = mv.emterentryid
where year(startdate) in (2013, 2014) and
      month(startdate) = 10
group by m.name;
```

EDIT:

You can generalize this for any date if you want:

```
with d as (
      select date('2014-10-10') as dte
     )
select m.name,
       sum(case when year(startdate) = 2014 and day(startdate) <= day(d.dte) then summary_value end) as thisyear,
       sum(case when year(startdate) = 2013 and day(startdate) <= day(d.dte) then summary_value end) as lastyear
from d cross join
     meters m join
     meter_values mv
     on m.meterentryid = mv.emterentryid
where year(startdate) (year(d.dte), year(d.dte) - 1) and
      month(startdate) = month(d.dte)
group by m.name;
```

Comment: Doesn't find the last date logged of the chosen date's month. But I figured it wouldn't provide with decent results even if it did. So this ends up working perfectly. Thank you!  so much simpler. Best regards